# Firefox not recognizing negative margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, margin

Please check this page: http://www.qhs.co.uk/high-wycombe-boiler-installation

```
#wrap .pushup {
  margin-top: -215px;
}
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Apparently it doesn't recognize a negative margin.

**Chrome (correct):**
[image: chrome]

**Firefox (wrong):**
[image]

I thought it could be a floating divs issue. I tried using the clearfix and moving the `.pushup` class in an outer div, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.

Comment: Have you tried `float: left`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `.jumbotron > .container > .row > .col-xs-12 { height:100%; }`  it should show correctly in firefox.

Answer (score 3):

FF is very hard to understand when it comes to negative margin. So instead of using negative margin,use  relative positioning.

```
#wrap .pushup {
  position:relative;
  top:-215px;
}
```

Comment: Is this code working for you? I tried it in browser in its working fine

Comment: Thanks, it is working indeed, but I chose the other answer because we probably shouldn't have set an `height: 100%` at first place.